# Get current month in Eleventy using Nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, date, nunjucks, eleventy, jamstack

Just trying to get the current month in Eleventy with a shortcode but having a bit of trouble.

Here's where I'm at:

```
config.addShortcode("month", () => {
let d = new Date();
let month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var n = month[d.getMonth()]; 

return n;
    })
```

All responses are very much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: [`() => new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" })`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). Also, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

This way is easier.

```js
const currentMonth = (new Date()).toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'long'});
console.log(currentMonth);
```